# Best way to record your own voice during a presentation

Tags: audio, microphone, sound

When I give a talk, I generally record the screen, plus there's a video recording of the room. I want to record the voice too, and annoyingly enough, the tiny little radio microphones that people use at conferences typically need a receiver. It's great when a conference has one, but sometimes they don't.

My question: what is the best way to record my own voice? I cannot realistically use a wired mic attached to the laptop b/c I might be moving about the room. I'm thinking maybe Bluetooth or some such? Whatever it is, it needs to be something wearable so I can move about.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a lavalier (lapel microphone) attached to a small recorder in your pocket will do the job.

Comment: Found a Sennheiser model, but $600... seriously?

Comment: Zoom H1 ($80) + Rode Lavalier mic ($249) will do the job :)

Answer (score 3):

Rode also came up with some software for your phone. Check it out at 
http://www.rodemic.com/software/roderec
http://www.rodemic.com/mics/smartlav

Here the video:

!

Comment: This is neat stuff, though not sure about using an iPhone :)

Comment: This is the best way to do it - even if you don't have an iPhone, buy an iPod touch (they're like $100 2nd hand) and pop it in your pocket when recording.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to [Musicshake.com](http://Musicshake.com) using in your computer as a audio recorder. It offers a wide array of genres and instruments to choose from, and even provides a suite of voice recording and editing features.

Comment: Please refrain from adding links that have nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: Also, I don't think that a web based recording app will help the OP much when he needs a portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikihow.com/Record-Your-Voice-on-a-Windows-Computer

hope this will help you...
REGARDS!

Comment: I think you're missing the point - I know how to record things, I just need the right hardware.